# Is Randomized Complete Block Design a two-way anova?

Tags: self-study, anova, references, experiment-design, blocking

Isn't Randomized Complete Block Design a two-way anova ? Can it be one-way ?

As far i understand, since there is treatment effect and also block effect in RCBD, it is two-way anova.

But can it be argued that in RCBD i am not interested in blocking . So it is one-way. 
Whereas in two-factor factorial design i am interested in both factors that why this two-factor factorial design is a two-way anova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RCBD is a kind of two-way ANOVA, surely. (ANOVA means analysis of Variance, and RCBD is usually analyzed that way, yes?).  It might also be other ways of using two-way ANOVA, no problem.